How do I fit the card view to the size of the recycler view?
I am making a list with a recycler view and in each view item I want to put a card view, but it doesn't fit the full size, as shown in the image.
recylcerview code where it has the screen size
recyclerview code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="List"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFE"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="F - E" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPS"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="P - S" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewNumero"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="#"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="date"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="hour"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="repetitions"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="speed"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="state"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/black" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/Lista_registro"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </FrameLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



cardview code:
cardview code where it does not fit to the desired size
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:cardMaxElevation="1dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_numero"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="#"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_fecha"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="date"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_hora"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="hour"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_rep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="R"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_vel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="S"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_estado"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

How could I modify or change the code so that the list fits correctly in the recycler view, taking into account the screen size?
